# Page size in List By Factory method in REST API

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-rest-api

I'm trying to list all the pipelines stored in the Azure Data Factory instance. I want to use Azure Data Factory REST API v2, [Pipelines - List By Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/listbyfactory) method.

I noticed the "nextLink" field in the [PipelineListResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/listbyfactory#pipelinelistresponse), which contains the link to the next page of results, if any remaining results exist.

My question is, how many `PipelineResource`s are sent in a single page of the response?

I didn't find any documentation regarding this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many PipelineResources are sent in a single page of the response?

In normal, the list operation response includes the `nextLink` property when the list operation returns more than 1,000 items. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#async-operations-throttling-and-paging).
[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you! It was definitely helpful :)